# How to get the total amount of video starts from this table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an Actions table structured out like below:

| Field Name | Data Type | Definition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Date | DATE | Date of Action - MM-DD-YYYY (ex. 10-01-2019) |
| action_type | varchar(255) | The type of action: signups, logins, video starts, video pauses, link clicks |
| user_id | varchar(255) | Unique ID for each visitor action |

And one of the questions I am being requested is what is the total amount of video starts on January 2nd, 2019.

Since the Action Type field is varchar, and not an int, would I use SUM(*)?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT SUM(*)
FROM Actions
WHERE DATE = '01-02-2019'
AND action_type = 'video starts';
```

Comment: Ad sample data and wanted result from it, and I think you want to just : `COUNT ()` https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-count/

Comment: Date of Action - MM-DD-YYYY - no way date columns are stored yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Actions
WHERE DATE = '01-02-2019'
AND action_type = 'video starts';
```

Comment: Thanks. Why would you use COUNT over SUM? Still learning. : )

Comment: @Bo.Allen If you were aggregating rows with a numeric column, for instance price, you could use `SUM` to calculate the total price by group entry. In your case you just want to count the number of rows having specific properties. Also note that `COUNT(*)` does not need a column name since you're counting rows, whereas `SUM` needs a numeric column to work on.